# Angular does not wait for <p-dialog> user confirmation while running in loop

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to implement copy paste action and if user selects multiple items paste and if file name exist in the destivation folder then dialog box should come and user should enter new name for that item and continue to paste.

however angular is not waiting for  box to open and not allowing user to enter new name,instead it opens at the end.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tree-demo-96zfra?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

here is my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.pasteFiles.length; i++) {
let ispresent = this.checkIfFileExist(file);
if (ispresent) {
this.dataService.setfilepath(file.newFilePath + '/' + file.pasteFileName);
this.callpastedialog(); //this.display=true; dint work
} else {
this.mainpaste(file);
}


callpastedialog(){   //tried to call it in seperate fun but no use
this.display=true;
}
```

html:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display">
.....
</p-dialog>
```

what is the way to resolve such issues?

Comment: Pretty sure an async function must return a Promise

Comment: async was not required

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried async/await in Angular, but why don't you use recursive function for your usecase instead

```
getNextFileToProcess() {
  const file = this.pasteFiles.shift();
  if (file) {
    if (fileExists()) {
      showPopup();
      whenActionComplete() {
        getNextFileToProcess();
      }
    } else {
      processFile();
      getNextFileToProcess()
    }
  } else {
    // processing complete
  }
}
```

Comment: instead i find using in loop easy but here the issue is with opening dialog wind one by one , how will that be resolved?

Comment: I do not see any reason, why the for loop would wait even if the async/await was to work. Because your function callpastedialog() is just setting a variable, and the function would complete instantaneosly, resulting in the for loop to process the next item. And as JavaScript is running in a single thread, only when all the items are done processing, the popup would open.

Comment: And the behavior that your are expecting is similar to how the confirm() works, and creating a custom modal component to mimic that behavior would be quite some work IMO.

Comment: you mean cannot make it work with p-dialog?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it with a p-dialog. There is ConfirmDialog which might help to some extent, but that will be similar to the browsers confirm() implementation. But you can take a look athe ConfirmService implementation if you want to build a custom behavior.

Comment: is there no way to use dialog box and oop the dialogbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234694/discussion-between-s-d-and-nayak).